# Work around for signal and slot argument limitation

Tags: qt, qt4

I want to make a PushButton when it is clicked, its text change into 'clicked'. I tried it by

```
connect(button1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(markClicked(button1)));
```

where `this` refer to the `MainWindow` and

```
void MainWindow::markClicked(QPushButton *button) { button->setText("Clicked"); }
```

It does not seem to work because I think SLOT cannot take more arguments than SIGNAL. If there any approach to work around this limitation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt signals/slots mechanism can only transfer signal to slot function with *similar parameters*. As a workaround, you should use [QSignalMapper](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qsignalmapper.html):

```
QSignalMapper mapper;
...
connect(button1, SIGNAL(clicked()), &mapper, SLOT(map()));
mapper.setMapping(button1, button1); // not sure whether this is mandatory or not
...
connect(&mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QWidget*)), this, SLOT(markClicked(QWidget*)));
```

and function *markClicked* is

```
void MainWindow::markClicked(QWidget *widget) {
  QPushButton *button = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(widget);
  button->setText("Clicked");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other way you could do this is to use a default value for the argument and then use the sender() method:
In MainWindow: 
    `void markClicked(QPushButton *button = NULL);`

then:
`connect(button1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(markClicked()));`

and:

```
void MainWindow::markClicked(QPushButton *button) {
   if (button==NULL) { button = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender()); }
    button->setText("Clicked");
}
```